# Opencover - No results with NUnit3 from command line

Tags: nunit-3.0, opencover

I am trying to get the code coverage with Opencover but I am getting below output always.

[image]

My batch files contents are like:

```
"..packages\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe" ^
-register:user ^
-target:"%..\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe" ^
-targetargs:"..\bin\Debug\Calculator_V3_Tests_NUnit.dll" ^
-filter:"+[Calculator_V3.Modules*]*" ^
-output:"..\TestResults.xml"
```

I have read lot of posts and tried -register:administrator or removing double quotes around dll and other options on the posts but nothing has worked. What I am missing here?

Thanks a lot in Advance!!

Comment: I was able to resolve this using [-filter:"+[Calculator_V3]*" ]. So in filters we have to give the assembly names. My bad,I had provided the name of the namespace earlier. Thanks.

Comment: I would always recommend that people use the default filters and then use the output 
file to guide them on the filters